# Solr synonyms - Issue with word containing wild card

Tags: solr, solr4, synonym

I have a `synonyms.txt` file which contains my synonyms keywords. When I search using wild card, the synonym is not matching the word.

Eg, my `synonyms.txt`:

> cable,rope, wire, chain, cordage

When I search `cable`, the synonyms are getting build as expected, but when I search `cable*`, I am not getting synonyms generated.

Please let me know if there is any work around for this, or is there a way to build custom `SynonymsFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make search like this:

```
cable OR cable*
```

This way Solr will search the exactly term `cable` and your synonyms and `cable*` will search every terms that starts with `cable`.

Comment: Thank you, but when i search for wire OR wire* the results are inconsistent. When i analyse  found that wildcard is not applied to synonym word

Comment: Try to use the param `q.op=AND` to see if your results turn consistent.